# Explanation for v-> v>5

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream

I have a given function call and java gives me an error because Objects are not comparable to ints (of course...). Can someone explain to me what I have to change?

I tried to brace the lambda expression differently but with no useful result. I think, that the lambda expression is correct and the filter-function is slightly wrong, but I'm not able to find out my mistake...

```
// function call
filter(v -> v > 5)

// function
public Optional<T> filter(Predicate<T> tester) {
    if(isPresent() && tester.test(get())) {
        return this;
    } else {
    return Optional.empty();
    }
}
```

I would expect a Optional.empty-Object but I get a java-error because `v > 5` Object v is not comparable to an int.

Comment: It would be good to look at the complete code block as well. Where are you using `filter` and what's the result you're trying to infer?

Comment: It's impossible. You return `this` meaning that your class should extend `Optional` which is `final`. Do you have your own `Optional`?

Answer (score 4):

You have to make `T` a wrapper class which is comparable with an int. e.g.

```
IntStream.range(0, 10)
         .filter(v -> v > 5)
         .forEach(System.out::println);
```

is fine because `v` is an `int`.

You can't use this expression when `T` is unknown.

What you can do is assume the `T` must be a number e.g.

```
filter( v -> ((Number) v).doubleValue() > 5)
```

however this will produce a ClassCastExpection is `T` is another type.

The real solution is to make `T` a `Number`

e.g.

```
class MyClass<T extends Number> {
    public Optional<T> filter(Predicate<T> test) {
```

or make it a specific type like int

```
class MyClass {
    public IntOptional filter(IntPredicate test) {
```

Comment: The class is a generic class. Casting `v` to `Number` and use `doubleValue()` to make it compatible to `Predicate<T>` looks like a hack.  The problem is at the root : the T declaration in the class.

Answer (score 3):

In Java primitives types (e.g. `int`) and objects (e.g. `Object`) don't have a common ancestor in the type hierarchy. Due to that predicates and other stream constructs come in two flavors e.g. there is [`IntPredicate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/function/IntPredicate.html) that you have to use when working with `int` and `Predicate` that you have to use when working with `Object`.

On way to write your filter function would be to use [`OptionalInt`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/OptionalInt.html) and `IntPredicate`:

```
public OptionalInt filter(IntPredicate tester) {
    if (isPresent() && tester.test(get())) {
        return ...
    } else {
        return OptionalInt.empty();
    }
}
```

Comment: Note: `Predicate<T>` where `T extends Number` would be fine.

Comment: @PeterLawrey you are absolutely right, boxing is another option.

Comment: Is there a way of achiev this without changing the Optional<T> and Predicate<T> in the function header? Because I don't really want to change the function header..

Comment: @PeterLawrey using `public Optional<T> filter(Predicate<T extends Number> tester) {` sadly doesn't work

Comment: @Hugugagegi You can only define `<T extends Number>` when you declared it the first tine, possibly on the `class Xxxx<T extends Number>` line.

Answer (score 3):

`v -> v > 5` can mean different things. It depends on context.

1. It could be a `(Object v) -> v > 5` causing a compilation error since `>` can't be applied to an `Object`:

   ```
   Stream.<Object>of("123", 123).filter(v -> v > 5);
   ```
2. It could be a `(Integer v) -> v > 5` meaning that unboxing and autoboxing will be performed in order to do the comparison and to return the result:

   ```
   Stream.<Integer>of(123, 123).filter(v -> v > 5);
   ```
3. It could be a `(int v) -> v > 5` meaning that it's an instance of [`IntPredicate`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/function/IntPredicate.html) and things will go smoothly here:

   ```
   IntStream.of(123, 123).filter(v -> v > 5);
   ```

Answer (score 2):

> I think, that the lambda expression is correct and the
>   filter-function is slightly wrong, but I'm not able to find out my
>   mistake...

You are right.
Your method seems to defeat the generic type declared  for the class as first of all your method is defined inside a generic class.

Supposing your class is named `Foo`, here the `filter()` method relies on the generic `T` type as return/parameter type :

```
public class Foo<T>{
     // ...
    public Optional<T> filter(Predicate<T> tester) { 
      // ...
    }
}
```

It works with inference.
So you get `Predicate` of `T`. But the `T` depends on the generic type defined in the class and also from the way which you declared the instance of the `Foo` class.
And it appears that here `T` is not a `Number`.

As alternative you could also rely on inference from the declared Foo variable.
If you do that :

```
Foo<Integer> foo = new Foo<>();
Optional<Integer> optInt = foo.filter(v -> v > 5);
```

it will compile fine as `Integer` will be inferred from `Foo<Integer>`.

So I think that to solve your issue, you should either declare Number or Integer as base class of the generic type :

```
public class Foo<T extends Integer>{
     // ...
    public Optional<T> filter(Predicate<T> tester) { 
      // ...
    }
}
```

or rely on the inference of the client as in the previous example.